# How to find $\Gamma(i)$?

Tags: complex-numbers, gamma-function

using the basic definition that $\Gamma(n)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{n-1}dx$
It would not be easy to find $\Gamma(i)$ then what method must be used to calculate it and would the result be real or complex?
Please Explain$_\cdots$

Comment: There are other definitions of $\Gamma(z)$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function (especially the Weierstrass product). Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut thank you btw can you help me with this question specifically?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function#Imaginary_and_complex_arguments

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Is there a proper derivation that i can understand

Comment: That link is indirectly telling that there is no known closed form for $\Gamma(i)$. Interestingly enough, we have $$ \lvert \Gamma(i) \rvert = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\sinh \pi}}. $$

Comment: @sangchul lee that is just the reflection formula, of course.  We can use it to check a numerical evaluation.

Comment: @OscarLanzi, Exactly, it is a consequence of the Euler's reflection formula. :)

Answer (score 1):

One approach:  The integral converges for $\Gamma (1+i)$.  Then, use the recursive relation to render $\Gamma (1+i) = i \Gamma (i)$.

Comment: $i$ is not real number to use recursive relation

Comment: @Euler'sDad, $\Gamma$ satisfies the functional equation $\Gamma(z+1) = z\Gamma(z)$ for *all* complex $z$ except for non-positive integers $z=0,-1,-2,\cdots$.